# Why does the output look like different?

Tags: shell-script, array

After executing this script, sometimes the output looks like this:

```
1912:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.13343774 Ry
2310:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.20757070 Ry
2709:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.24296462 Ry
3084:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.25563488 Ry
3483:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.27085564 Ry
3870:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.27693129 Ry
4245:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.28213580 Ry
4632:!    total e
ergy              = -1090.29131927 Ry
```

and sometimes like this:

```
1912:!    total energy              = -1090.13343774 Ry
2310:!    total energy              = -1090.20757070 Ry
2709:!    total energy              = -1090.24296462 Ry
3084:!    total energy              = -1090.25563488 Ry
3483:!    total energy              = -1090.27085564 Ry
3870:!    total energy              = -1090.27693129 Ry
4245:!    total energy              = -1090.28213580 Ry
```

Is it just a bug or do I change something in the code unintentionally ?

The code:

```
cm=$1
nm=$2
case $cm in
    "out")
        declare -a  en
        ec=$(grep -n "! " hw1_out_si_wire.txt)
        IFS='\n' en=($ec)
        for i in ${en[@]}
        do
            echo "$i"
        done
        ;;
    "in") echo "It's not my problem";;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFS='\n'` sets the internal field separator to consist of two characters: `\` (backslash) and the letter `n`. Use `IFS=$'\n'` instead which sets it to contain the newline only.